# How to ask Mathematica to give NumberLinePlot of $\sin x$ for non-integer $x$?

Tags: plotting

How to ask Mathematica to give `NumberLinePlot` of $\sin x$ on domain $x\in(0,30)\notin\mathbb{N}$. I need solution for non-integer $x$

`NumberLinePlot[{Sin[x] < 0, Sin[x] >= 0}, {x, 0, 30}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could include an additional predicate:

```
NumberLinePlot[
    {
    Sin[x] < 0 && Mod[x, 1] != 0, 
    Sin[x] >= 0 && Mod[x, 1] != 0
    },
    {x, 0, 30}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
positiveSol = 
 x /. Solve[
   Sin[x] > 0 && 0 < x < 30 && x ∈ PositiveIntegers]
negativeSol = 
 x /. Solve[
   Sin[x] < 0 && 0 < x < 30 && x ∈ PositiveIntegers]
NumberLinePlot[! AnyTrue[positiveSol, EqualTo[x]], {x, 0, 30}]
NumberLinePlot[! AnyTrue[negativeSol, EqualTo[x]], {x, 0, 30}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `positiveSol = 
 x /. Solve[
   Sin[x] > 0 && 0 < x < 30 && x ∈ PositiveIntegers];
negativeSol = 
 x /. Solve[
   Sin[x] < 0 && 0 < x < 30 && x ∈ PositiveIntegers];
NumberLinePlot[{Sin[x] > 0 && ! AnyTrue[positiveSol, EqualTo[x]], 
  Sin[x] < 0 && ! AnyTrue[negativeSol, EqualTo[x]]}, {x, 0, 30}]`